# Displaying values from mysql by jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I got a problem with displaying data which i downloaded earlier by json from mysql. My problem is displaying value only in parent input. 
This code runs great but i've to change only parent input value:

```
    function wstaw(nazwa,vat,cena)
{ 
$("#netto").val(cena);
$("#towar").val(nazwa);
$("#vat").val(vat);
        };

$('.rezultaty', parent).append('<a href="#" onclick="wstaw(' + val.name + ',' + val.id + ',' + val.vat + ')">' + val.name + '</a><br />');
```

I wrote that code but i have problem with ' and " can you help me with that?

```
 $('.rezultaty', parent).append('<a href="#" onclick="'('towar', parent).val(' + val.name + ') ('netto', parent).val(' + val.id + ') ('vat', parent).val(' + val.vat + ')'">' + val.name + '</a><br />');
```

Sorry for my bed English :)

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, create the `a` element and directly bind the event handler with jQuery. Then you don't have any hassle with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

for first statement use this

```
$('.rezultaty', parent).append("<a href='#' onclick='wstaw(" + val.name + "," + val.id + "," + val.vat + ")' >" + val.name + "</a><br />");
```

and for last statement use this

```
$('.rezultaty', parent).append("<a href='#' onclick='"+("towar", parent).val(" + val.name + ") ("netto", parent).val(" + val.id + ") ("vat", parent).val(" + val.vat + ")+"'>" + val.name + "</a><br />");
```